# Is there a way to get write access to twitter api without mobile authentication?

Tags: twitter

I am currently working out of india and am trying to get to make my app post on behalf of my Twitter user account. However, for me to be able to do this, I need to create write access to my app on twitter, which I tried to. Unfortunately, twitter gives me the following error:

> Error
>
> You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before granting your application write capabilities. Please read https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web for more information

Now, I tried to add my mobile phone number following these instructions. Twitter, does not support any of the Indian mobile carriers in order to authenticate the same.

Is there a work around? Is there any way I can make write access work from here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

The official way to do this is to contact the Twitter API team directly using this form https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform

The unofficial way is

- Authenticate against mobile.twitter.com (use your phone or computer).
- Go to Settings
- Go to Phone
- Add
- Add your mobile
- A "manage" link should be available
- All being well, you'll get a confirmation SMS

I've not tried this method - but I have seen other people say it works.